# Given a list of uneven probabilities, what is chance of at least one occurring?

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I'm writing a Python program that has a list of probabilities.  Each probability represents a catastrophic outcome of an event:

```
# doing six different events, the array is the risk of each having a bad outcome:
list = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4]
```

Each event can happen once or more. Their order is irrelevant. More than one event can have the same probability. How would I calculate the chance that **one or more** of these events occur?

*My apologies it this is a basic question.  It's been many years since I had anything like this is school, and the terminology is difficult when I search for this.  Khan academy did not seem to provide an answer either.  If the answer is simple, just telling me what to search for would suffice.  Thanks in advance! (:*

Comment: Is `0.2` the probability the first event will happen once or that it will happen once or more?

Comment: if each decimal number (`0.2`, `0.1` ... ) is probability of an event happening once, and if all events are independent of each other(including itself), then please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way to look at this problem is to think about the opposite question: what's the probability of **none** of these events happening? That is, what is the probability that

Event 1 doesn't happen AND Event 2 doesn't happen AND etc.

This is simply the product

(1 - p1) * (1 - p2) * .....

for each of the probabilities which results in a probability p_none. Then take the opposite of that:

(1 - p_none)

and you have the probability of one or more events occurring.

Comment: Thank you, this was logical, and a good answer. Guess it was pretty basic, like I suspected (;

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want 1 - (chance of no events occurring) which is easy.  Start with 1 and go through the list multiplying by 1 - number:

psuedocode:

```
result = 1
foreach item in list
  result = result * (1 - item)
end foreach
return 1 - result
```

Comment: You forgot the final step, which is to return (1-result). This will give you the chance of no events happening.

Answer (score 1):

If the probabilities listed are each the probability that event i happens 1 or more times then this should work:

prob 1 or more happens == 1.0 - prob none of them happen

prob none happen = product of probabilities each event i doesn't happen

prob event i doesn't happen = 1.0 - prob event i happens

Of course this assumes that each event category is independent.

So in your case prob = 1.0 - (1.0-0.2)*(1.0-0.1)*(1.0-0.4)*(1.0-0.3)*(1.0-0.2)*(1.0-0.4)